# Parse tree using Bison

Tags: bison, abstract-syntax-tree

I am new to Bison. I am trying to implement a parser. The main problem that I am facing is with the parse tree. I am getting an error related to the tree which I am unable to eliminate. It says "unknown type name 'tree' ". Here is my y file. I would be glad if anyone could help me sort out this. I need the parser very badly. Thanks in advance.

```
%{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 void yyerror(const char *str)
 {
    fprintf(stderr,"error FAIL: %s\n",str);
 }

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
} 

enum treetype {operator_node, variable_node};
typedef struct tree {
enum treetype nodetype;
union {
 struct {struct tree *left, *right; char operator;} an_operator;
  char *a_variable;
} body;
} tree;
static tree *make_op (tree *l, char o, tree *r) {
tree *result= (tree*) malloc (sizeof(tree));
result->nodetype= operator_node;
result->body.an_operator.left= l;
result->body.an_operator.operator= o;
result->body.an_operator.right= r;
return result;
}
static void printtree (tree *t, int level) {
#define step 4
if (t)
 switch (t->nodetype)
 {
   case operator_node:
    printtree (t->body.an_operator.right, level+step);
    printf ("%*c%c\n", level, ' ', t->body.an_operator.operator);
    printtree (t->body.an_operator.left, level+step);
    break;
   case variable_node:
    printf ("%*c%c\n", level, ' ', t->body.a_variable);
 }
} 

%}

%union {
char* a_variable;
tree* a_tree;
}

%start file
%token <a_variable> TOKDIGIT TOKFLOAT TOKID TOKSEMICOLON TOLCOLON TOKCOMMA TOKUNRECOG   TOKCOMMENT TOKDOT TOKMINUS TOKCOLON
%type <a_tree> field object file ID
%right TOKMINUS

%%

file   :    
   |    object file { printtree($1, 1); }
    ;
object :     field object {$$ = make_op($1, '', $2);}
  |   field {$$ = $1 ; }
    ;
field  :    ID TOKCOLON field {$$ = make_op ($1, ':', $3); }
  | ID TOKCOMMA field {$$ = make_op ($1, ',', $3); }
  | ID TOKSEMICOLON field {$$ = make_op ($1, ';', $3); }
    ;   
ID     :   TOKID { $$ = $1; }
       ;    

%%
```

Answer (score 2):

I applied the following patch to your code to fix a couple of warnings out of Bison. Your top level rule was missing an action for the empty case (and thus failing to assign to `$$`) and the other rule there was also not assigning anything to `$$`. I.e. your `file` rules are not accumulating the objects into a master tree, and so your `yyparse` function will not return a tree:

```
Index: test/test.y
===================================================================
--- test.orig/test.y    2012-03-15 16:34:31.992021757 -0700
+++ test/test.y 2012-03-15 17:00:27.666596757 -0700
@@ -57,8 +57,9 @@

 %%

-file   :    
-   |    object file { printtree($1, 1); }
+file   :   /* empty */ { return NULL; }
+   |    object file { printtree($1, 1); return NULL; }
+        /* TODO: gather the objects into a tree and return */
     ;
 object :     field object {$$ = make_op($1, '', $2);}
   |   field {$$ = $1 ; }
```

Now, you have problems in the grammar. The main one is that your `field` productions do not terminate. They generate infinite sentences. Every one of the productions for `field` produces something that ends with `field`; there is no way for the grammar expansion to end.

The main problem is that there are too many places in your grammar where expansion takes place, and over the same stuff.  Your `file` produces zero or more `object`. An `object` is zero more instances of `field`. And then a field also wants to generate more `field`.

What this means is that your `file` is really just a sequence of `field`. The sequencing of multiple `field`-s is already handled, and it has to be handled in one level only; field does not have to produce more `field`.

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you but still the error "unknown type name 'tree'" pops up when I try to compile the tab.c file. this is how the grammar looks like now:  
`file   :     /*empty*/  { return NULL; }  
       |    field file { printtree($1, 1); return NULL; }  
      ;  
field  :    ID TOKCOLON field {$$ = make_op ($1, ':', $3); }  
      | ID TOKCOMMA field {$$ = make_op ($1, ',', $3); }  
      | ID TOKSEMICOLON field {$$ = make_op ($1, ';', $3); }  
        |  /* empty*/ { return NULL; }  
      ;  
ID     :   TOKID { $$ = $1; }  
           ;`

Comment: The problem is somewhere else; that looks like a C programming error about your `tree` typedef name. Are there no more error messages coming out of `yacc`?

Comment: Your `tree` type will probably have to be defined in a header file. You use `tree` in your Yacc `%union` which Yacc uses to generate the `YYSTYPE` parse node type. When you run `yacc -d` it generates a `y.tab.h` header file in which `YYSTYPE` is declared. If `%union` defines a `tree` type, then `YYSTYPE` will have a member of `tree` type. Whoever includes `y.tab.h` will have to also include the definition of `tree` from somewhere, or else the `YYSTYPE` declaration will be referencing an undefined type.

Comment: How do I define the `tree` in the header file? Also I am getting 5 shift/reduce conflicts and 2 reduce/reduce conflicts.. initially it was 6 and 4 but was reduced to 5 and 2 after I tweaked the grammar a bit

Comment: Create a file like `parser.h` or `tree.h` or whatever, and stick it there, the include that in your Yacc grammar file between the `%{` and `%}` and in any other file that needs it including any that include `y.tab.h` (prior to `#include "y.tab.h"`).

Comment: Any more complaints about useless rules and such?

Comment: I created an empty file and named it as `tree.h` and did exactly what you suggested but still the error persists.
As I told you, there are 5 shift/reduce and 2 reduce/reduce conflicts.

Comment: You should maybe start a new question and post the exact latest code that you have that is giving this `tree` problem. Or update the question. The original code you posted in the original question seems fine. There are functions that refer to `tree *` but there is a `typedef struct { ...} tree;`. That type will eventually have to break out into a header file so that your lexical analyzer can see it, (and other modules) but it should not appear to be missing in `y.tab.c` itself.

Comment: the latest code is very much the same except that I just changed the grammar a bit which I have updated in the first comment. Otherwise the rest of the code is the same.

Comment: I can run the original code through `yacc`, and compile it with `gcc`. It just complains about an unresolved symbol `yylex`, that is all, since there is no lexical analyzer. No error about a `tree`. diff what you have now against the original code.

Comment: Oh is it. why is that it is showing different errors for both of us?

Comment: Dunno. I just cut what you have above, pasted it into `cat > test.y` in a terminal window, then `yacc -d test.y` and `gcc y.tab.c`.  Of course I saw all those errors about useless rules and nonterminals in the original, but the code does get to the linking stage where it just fails on `yylex`.

Comment: But I don't see any errors related to useless rules now. Should I give you the lex file also so that you can test it real time?

Comment: I'd maybe even start a different question for that, you know.

Comment: Ok I'm gonna start a diff ques and this time I'll include both the lex and y files. Thanks a lot Kaz